# Getting both data and params data from ActivedRoute

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm currently using Angular and i have a web page that requires me to pass data to another page.

1. Pass a list of selected value (array)
2. Create multiple records (mapping to a model)

   ```
   this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ model] }) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           this.ngbModalRef = this.modalService.open(... as Component, { size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' });
           this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.model = model;
           this.ngbModalRef.result.then(
               result => {
                   console.log(result);
                  // this.router.navigate(['/order', { outlets: { popup: null } }]);
                   //this.ngbModalRef = null;
               },
               reason => {
                   console.log(reason);
                  // this.router.navigate(['/order', { outlets: { popup: null } }]);
                   //this.ngbModalRef = null;
               }
           );
       }, 0);
   });


   this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           this.ngbModalRef = this.modalService.open(... as Component, {
               size: 'lg',
               backdrop: 'static'
           });
           this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.listOfNum = params['listOfNum'];
           this.ngbModalRef.result.then(
               result => {
                   this.router.navigate(['/order', { outlets: { popup: null } }], {
                       replaceUrl: true,
                       queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
                   });
                   this.ngbModalRef = null;
               },
               reason => {
                   this.router.navigate(['/order', { outlets: { popup: null } }], {
                       replaceUrl: true,
                       queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
                   });
                   this.ngbModalRef = null;
               }
           );
       }, 0);
   });
   ```

Please advise what i can do to retrieve these two messages. I only managed to get the model data in this order.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use rxjs forkjoin method.

Forkjoin is getting an observable array and it is firing when all of them finish.

```
forkJoin(
     this.activatedRoute.data,
     this.activatedRoute.params
).subscribe(([model, params]) => {

    this.ngbModalRef = this.modalService.open(... as Component, {
        size: 'lg',
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
    this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.listOfNum = params['listOfNum'];
    this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.model = model;
});
```

But just keep that in your mind, it will **only and only** fire when **both of them complete**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have decided to use service to pass data.